# Android: cannot convert to JSONArray from multidimensional MongoDB jsonObject

Tags: android, json, mongodb

im trying to get data from the site which have mongodb as their database and CI ,i make simple script to  make json encode output from the site and the output is like :

```
   {
   "mko680": {
       "_id": {
       "$id": "515be1807bfb8b1d0d000000"
        },
       "channel": [
                  "channel a",
                  "subchannel a"
                  ],
       "channel_id": 227,
       "id": "mko680",
    }, 
   "mkv002": {
       "_id": {
       "$id": "515b32407bfb8b1d0d000000"
             },
       "channel": [
                 "channel a",
                 "subchannel b"
                   ],
       "channel_id": 232,
       "id": "mkv002",
  }
}
```

i try to parse that output in my android project like this

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(outputlike o);
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject json_data = obj.getJSONObject(i);
  Log.i("test",json_data.getString("channel_id"));
}
```

the logcat said org.JSON.Mismatch

any clue  for which is json/my code that not right ?

thanks , and sory for my bad question hope you understand

**UPDATED :**

now i change it to json object like :

```
JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(bufstring);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
Log.i("test",arr.getString("channel_id"));
}
```

but the logcat now said , no value for channel_id, but it sure there is channel_id in that output, any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you receive is of the type `JSONObject` and not `JSONArray`. Therefore, you need to parse your json data like this:-

```
String jsonStr = "..."; //Your JSONString
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONObject mkObj = obj.getJSONObject("mko680");
String channelId = mkObj.getString("channel_id");
```

Comment: thanks , yes i've do something like that to but i want to get all data from all mko680,mkv002 and others which i dont know what is the _id is , is that any way to do it while looping ?

Comment: if you've made your JSON like that, then put my code snippet in the `while` loop and it'll work.

Comment: here is my full json http://tny.cz/72d02fc2   , can you post the loop code , i try and it just show the first one (mko680) the others not

Answer (score 1):

Your return data is `Jsonobject` not an `JsonArray`.

So,  you can create `JsonObject`,

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(outputlike o);
```

Comment: thanks @rajeshwaran , first problem is solved but now there is another, see updated first post

Comment: please post your full json.

Comment: @Abdullah follow `R J` Answer

Answer (score 0):

thank all based on your answer i have figured it out, at first i got difficult to get dynamic key for getting the right object i use below code to solved it, dont think its the good one but i use this in temporary

```
JSONObject arr = new JSONObject(bufstring);   
 Iterator keys = arr.keys();
 while(keys.hasNext()) {
  String ambilKey = (String)keys.next();
  JSONObject AmbilObject = arr.getJSONObject(ambilKey);
  Log.i("test",AmbilObject.toString());
 }
```

thanks for all suggestion, you're rock :D